# How to choose other options from my list in Python

Tags: python, loops

```
print ("Calculadora de conversiones") 
opcion = int(input("***MENÚ*** \n1. Galones a Litros \n2. Litros a Galones \n3. Litros a mililitros \n4. Galones a mililitros \n" "Ingrese la opción que desea: "))
if opcion == 1:
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
    Galones=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de Galones a convertir:   "))
    Litros = Galones * 3.7854118
    print(Galones, "Galones equivalen a",Litros,"Litros")
if opcion == 2:
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
    Litros=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de Litros a convertir:   "))
    Galones = Litros / 3.7854118
    print(Litros, "Litros equivalen a",Galones,"Galones")   
if opcion == 3:
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
    Litros=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de Litros a convertir:  "))
    mililitros = Litros * 1000
    print(Litros, "Litros equivalen a",mililitros,"mililitros")   
if opcion == 4:
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
    Galones=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de Galones a convertir:  "))
    mililitros = Galones * 3785.41
    print(Galones, "Galones equivalen a",mililitros,"mililitros")
```

**I know it's in Spanish, I'm helping a friend :(**

I forgot the command to choose another option from the list again before using exit()

Comment: You seem to know about `if`. Do you also know about `elif`? The question isn't very clear. Are you uncertain about how to put code into a `while` loop? Just indent it below `while True` and make sure that one of the available options is able to break out of the loop.

Comment: DirtyBit that was what I needed, thanks!

Comment: If their answer is what you needed, consider marking their answer as "accepted" (by using the checkmark next to the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` loop to keep iterating the options, selecting any input value other than the ones provided i.e. integers `1,2,3,4` should break the loop and end the program.

```
print ("Calculadora de conversiones") 
while True:
    opcion = int(input("***MENÚ*** \n1. Galones a Litros \n2. Litros a Galones \n3. Litros a mililitros \n4. Galones a mililitros \n" "Ingrese la opción que desea: "))
    if opcion == 1:
        print("-------------------------------------------------")
        Galones=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de Galones a convertir:   "))
        Litros = Galones * 3.7854118
        print(Galones, "Galones equivalen a",Litros,"Litros")
    elif opcion == 2:
        print("-------------------------------------------------")
        Litros=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de Litros a convertir:   "))
        Galones = Litros / 3.7854118
        print(Litros, "Litros equivalen a",Galones,"Galones")   
    elif opcion == 3:
        print("-------------------------------------------------")
        Litros=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de Litros a convertir:  "))
        mililitros = Litros * 1000
        print(Litros, "Litros equivalen a",mililitros,"mililitros")   
    elif opcion == 4:
        print("-------------------------------------------------")
        Galones=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de Galones a convertir:  "))
        mililitros = Galones * 3785.41
        print(Galones, "Galones equivalen a",mililitros,"mililitros")
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `elif` (else if) and `else`

```
print ("Calculadora de conversiones")
opcion = int(input("***MENÚ***\n1. Galones a Litros \n2. Litros a Galones \n3. Litros a mililitros\n4. Galones a mililitros \n Ingrese la opción que desea: "))
if opcion == 1:
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
    Galones=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de Galones a convertir:   "))
    Litros = Galones * 3.7854118
    print(Galones, "Galones equivalen a",Litros,"Litros")
elif opcion == 2:
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
    Litros=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de Litros a convertir:   "))
    Galones = Litros / 3.7854118
    print(Litros, "Litros equivalen a",Galones,"Galones")
elif opcion == 3:
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
    Litros=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de Litros a convertir:  "))
    mililitros = Litros * 1000
    print(Litros, "Litros equivalen a",mililitros,"mililitros")
elif opcion == 4:
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
    Galones=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de Galones a convertir:  "))
    mililitros = Galones * 3785.41
    print(Galones, "Galones equivalen a",mililitros,"mililitros")
else:
    print("other option")
```